# How to forward model validation errors to a view based on another model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I created a data import page to centralize the feature, and remove numerous import controllers.

I have a DataImport object to grab parameters for the DataImports controller.
The controller identifies the required importation model, and kicks the importation script. If it is successfull, it renders imported objects index, if not, it comes back to the data import form.

As you can see, in case of validation failure, the **save** method from the **organisation_import.rb** model returns the error messages list. How can I pass this list of errors to the @data_import instance so that when rendering back the **new** view, errors are listed ?

Thanks for your help!

Model: **data_import.rb**

```
class DataImport
  include ActiveModel::Model
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor  :file, :playground_id, :object_type_id

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each { |name, value| send("#{name}=", value) }
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

View: **new.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, (t('DataImport'))) %>

<% provide :page_heading do %>
    <%= t('DataImport') %>
<% end %>

  <%= render partial: "shared/error_list", locals: { errors: @data_import.errors } %>

<div class="row mat-form-row">
  <div class="col-md-12"> <h3><%= t('DataImport') %></h3>
  </div>
</div>

<%= form_for @data_import, html: {id: "input_form"}  do |f| %>

  <div class="row mat-form-row">
    <div class="mat-form-field col-md-3">
      <%= f.label :object_type, t('ObjectType'), class: "mat-form-field-label" %>
      <%= f.collection_select :object_type_id, qdm_object_types('import'), :id, :name, {}, { class: "mat-input-element" } %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mat-form-row">
    <div class="mat-form-field col-md-3">
      <%= f.label :file, t('SourceFile'), class: "mat-form-field-label" %>
      <%= f.file_field :file, class: "mat-input-element" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="mat-form-field col-md-3">
      <%= f.label :playground, t('Playground'),  class: "mat-form-field-label" %>
      <%= f.collection_select :playground_id, list_of_playgrounds, :id, :translation, {}, { class: "mat-input-element" } %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mat-button-group">
    <%= link_to t('Cancel'), root_path, method: :get, class: "mat-stroked-button mat-button-base"  %>
    <%= submit_tag(t('Submit'), :onclick => "submitform();", class: "mat-flat-button mat-button-base mat-primary" ) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller: **data_imports_controller.rb**

```
class DataImportsController < ApplicationController
  # Check for active session
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @data_import = DataImport.new
  end

  def create
    @data_import = DataImport.new(params[:data_import])
    if @data_import.file.nil?
      render :new, notice: t('FileNameCannotBeEmpty')
    end
    objects = Parameter.find(@data_import.object_type_id).name.downcase.pluralize
    objects_import = "#{objects}Import".classify.constantize
    @imported = objects_import.new(file: @data_import.file, playground: @data_import.playground_id)

    if @imported.save
      redirect_to "/#{objects}", notice: t('ImportedObjects')
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

Example of **organisations_import.rb** model:

```
class OrganisationsImport
  include ActiveModel::Model
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :file, :playground

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each { |name, value| send("#{name}=", value) }
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    if imported_organisations.map(&:valid?).all?
      imported_organisations.each(&:save!)
      true
    else
      imported_organisations.each_with_index do |column, index|
        column.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          errors.add :base, "Row #{index+2}: #{message}"
        end
      end
      false
    end
  end

  def imported_organisations
    @imported_organisations ||= load_imported_organisations
  end

  def load_imported_organisations
    spreadsheet = self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    spreadsheet.default_sheet = 'Organisations'
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
      record = Organisation.new
      record.playground_id = $Unicity ? 0 : playground # If only one tenant, then the organisations belong to Governance
      record.code = spreadsheet.cell(i,1).to_s
      record.name = spreadsheet.cell(i,6)
      record.parent_code = spreadsheet.cell(i,2).to_s # before_save action sets the parent_id
      record.organisation_level = spreadsheet.cell(i,3) # overwriten by the before_save action
      record.created_by = 'admin'
      record.updated_by = 'admin'
      record.owner_id = 1 # Administrator
      record.status_id = Parameter.find_by_name("New").id if Parameter.exists?(:name => ("New"))

      # Add description translations
      next_cell = 6
      ApplicationController.helpers.list_of_languages.order(:property).each do |translation|
        record.description_translations.build(field_name: 'name', language: translation.property, translation: spreadsheet.cell(i,next_cell))
        next_cell += 1
        record.description_translations.build(field_name: 'description', language: translation.property, translation: spreadsheet.cell(i,next_cell))
        next_cell += 1
      end
      puts "####################### test ####################################"
      puts record.attributes

      record
    end
  end

  def open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, csv_options: {col_sep: ";"})
#    when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append error messages to your `@data_import` object's errors.

```
@imported.errors.full_messages.each{|msg| @data_import.errors[:base] << msg}
```